# Error using AWS Signature V4 - The request signature we calculated does not match

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to call an AWS sagemaker end points and have looked at the following instructions to sign the request: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html. It is in python but I have done my best to implement it in TypeScript. Here are the two main functions:

```
getModelResult(request: ProceedsAIRequest): Observable<string> {
        // get x-Amz-Date
        var amzDate = this.getAmzDate(new Date().toISOString());
        let headers: HttpHeaders;
        let payload = request.toCSV();

        let signature = this.createSignature(payload);

        let auth = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 ' +
                   `Credential=${this.config.settings.AWSKey}/${this.getYYYYMMDD()}/us-east-2/sagemaker/aws4_request, ` + 
                   'SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, ' + 
                   `Signature=${signature}`;
        
        let amzContent = CryptoJS.SHA256(payload).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

        headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': auth,
            'content-type': 'text/csv',
            'X-Amz-Content-Sha256': amzContent,
            'X-Amz-Date': amzDate});

        let options = { headers: headers };

        console.log('headers', headers);
        
        return this.http.post<string>(this.config.settings.AIUrl, payload, options);
    }
```

The main logic is in createSignature - which is here:

```
    createSignature(payload: string): string {
        var amzDate = this.getAmzDate(new Date().toISOString());
        let amzContent = CryptoJS.SHA256(payload).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        let host = 'runtime.sagemaker.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'

        // task 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST
        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html
        
        // Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.
        // Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query 
        let canonicalUri = this.config.settings.AIUrl;
        canonicalUri = '/endpoints/proceeds-classificationv1-<my endpoint GUID>/invocations';

        // Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
        // request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
        // be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
        let canonicalQueryString = '';
        
        // Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
        // must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from
        // low to high. Note that there is a trailing \n.
        // content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
        let canonicalHeaders = 'content-type:text/csv\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-content-sha256:' + amzContent + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzDate + '\n'
        
        // Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
        // in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
        // Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
        // signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the 
        // hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
        let signedHeaders = 'content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date';
        
        // # Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
        let payloadHash = amzContent;
        
        // Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
        let canonicalRequest = 'POST' + '\n' + canonicalUri + '\n' + canonicalQueryString + '\n' + canonicalHeaders + '\n' + signedHeaders + '\n' + payloadHash
        
        
        // TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
        // # Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
        // # SHA-256 (recommended)
        let algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
        let credentialScope = this.getYYYYMMDD() + '/' + 'us-east-2' + '/' + 'sagemaker' + '/' + 'aws4_request';
        let stringToSign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzDate + '\n' +  credentialScope + '\n' +  CryptoJS.SHA256(canonicalRequest).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
        
        // TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
        // Create the signing key using the function defined above.
        let signingKey = this.getSigningKey();
        
        // Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
        return CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    }
```

AWS returns "The request signature we calculated does not match"

I have tried using some 3rd party wrappers to sign the request without success. I have tried to use the AWS Sagemaker Javascript SDK and the documentation is horrible.

I feel like I am close but it is difficult to troubleshoot. Any thoughts or guidance?